# How to create a email button to one person?

Tags: email, button, dynamic, powerbi, desktop

I'm trying to create a email button in Power BI Desktop. So my users can contact me easily.

I don't want a dynamic button with filter or something like that, just me.

I create a field with :  name.lastname@company.com

I said it's url.

I create the button.

In "action" i said that the type is "Web url" too and in the conditionnal field i put my table witch contains only my mail.

And it doesn't work. I don't wanna multiples mails or anything like that. Just a button with my email.

Do you know how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a table/column with your email in format //email@domain.com

Select this new column -> go to Column tools -> Data category and select Web URL

Create a new visualization, add this new column. You should see a hyperlink where after clicking it default mail program should run (outlook in my case);

[image]

[image]